# Update a field according to a query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have two tables:

```
Table 1 - [EmployeeERP]:

[EMER_ID] - My Own Identity - primary key
[EMER_CreateDate]
[EMER_EmployeeID]
[EMER_EmployeeNumber]



Table 2 - [ERP_TEST]:

[ERPT_ID] -  My Own Identity - primary key
[ERPT_EmployeeNumber]
[ERPT_EmployeeID]
[ERPT_IsDuplicate]
```

I wrote this command to take data from one table to another:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ERP_TEST] ([ERPT_ID],[ERPT_EmployeeNumber],[ERPT_EmployeeID])
select [EMER_ID],[EMER_EmployeeNumber],[EMER_EmployeeID] from [dbo].[EmployeeERP]
```

Later I wrote this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
select [EMER_EmployeeID] , count(*) as cnt
from  [dbo].[EmployeeERP]
group by [EMER_EmployeeID]
) as T
where T.cnt > 1
```

Now, I want that in the table `[ERP_TEST]` in the field `**ERPT_IsDuplicate**` there will be 1 (int) if the the `EMER_EmployeeID` in the `EmployeeERP` table  is duplicate and 0 (int) otherwise.

Can you help me?

Comment: Please tag dbms use.

Comment: What do you mean by "is duplicate"?

Comment: That the values for EMER_EmployeeNumber was found mor than one record in the EmployeeERP table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the flag to refer to employee ids that are duplicated in the `EmployeeERP` table, then you can use a `join`:

```
update t
    set erpt_isduplicate = (case when e.cnt > 1 then 1 else 0 end)
    from erp_test t left join
         (select [EMER_EmployeeID], count(*) as cnt
          from  [dbo].[EmployeeERP]
          group by [EMER_EmployeeID]
         ) e
         on e.emer_employeeid = t.ERPT_EmployeeID;
```

I am assuming that you are using SQL Server, based on your syntax.